# How can I neglect everything after a character in a string?

Tags: c++, string, shell, token, strtok

I am trying to modify the strtok() function in C++ where if a '#' character is reached while a char pointer iterates through the string, then everything after that character is neglected and nothing more is returned from the function. In my code, I included the extra if statement that if the char pointer reaches the '#' character, return everything before it and terminate the process by using a break statement. A bool variable is also used to control the loop in the main function so that if it changes value it would prevent an infinite loop.

However, the code still results in an infinite loop and so is my thought process.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
char *userdefine_strtok(char *arg, string delimiter, bool &breaker)
{
    static int pos = 0;
    static char* buf = 0;
    static char* token = 0;

    if (arg)
    {
        //start a new search
        pos = 0;
        buf = arg;

        //delete previous token if any
        if (token) delete token;

        //create token at least as big as the argument
        token = new char[strlen(buf) + 1];
    }

    if (!buf)
        return 0;

    if (pos >= strlen(buf))
        return 0;

    //prepare the token
    memset(token, 0, strlen(buf) + 1);

    int i = 0;
    while (pos < strlen(buf))
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < delimiter.length(); j++) {
        if (buf[pos] == delimiter[j])
        {
            pos++;
            return token;
        }

        }

        if (buf[pos] == '#')
        {
            return token; //return everything before character
            breaker = false; //bool is false so while loop in main will not continue
            break;//break out of the current loop
        }

        token[i] = buf[pos];
        i++;
        pos++;


    }

    return token;
}

int main()
{
    bool stopper = true;
    char *buf = "hello,world#1a,2!b,3c";
    cout << "String is :" << buf << endl << endl;
    char *token = userdefine_strtok(buf, ",!", stopper);
    while (token && stopper)
    {
        std::cout << token << "\n";
        token = userdefine_strtok(NULL, ",!", stopper);

    }


    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *if a '#' character is reached while a char pointer iterates through the string, then everything after that character is neglected* -- Why not simply trim the string first of the junk characters, and *then* tokenize it?  That would be much simpler than trying to tokenize a polluted string.

Comment: Plus, why are you using `C` routines to do this?  Why not stick with `std::string` all the way and work with `std::string`?  There is no need to resort to `char *`, `strlen`, etc.

Comment: Isn't that what tokenizing does already? Tokenizing should already be trimming the string of the junk characters which are the tokens if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Your method is very confusing and convoluted.  The sane way is to make sure the string is rid of garbage characters first, then the tokenization starts.  That makes this whole thing a lot simpler.   Then it's simply `mystring.erase(std::find(mystring.begin(), mystring.end(), '#'), mystring.end());` gets rid of all the junk, including the `#`.  Then tokenize `mystring`.

Comment: I am working on a shell assignment in class and most of the resources online are C programs and use char* pointers instead of strings. I could use strings in substitution, but how would that help the code?

Comment: So if I got rid of all the delimiters including '#' then how would the resulting string know where the '#' originally was and throw away everything after where it was initially placed? I should also mention that the tokenizing already works with that function, it's when I try to include '#' to the program to accomplish the objective, then it starts infinite looping.

Comment: You can still use algorithms if the data is `char *`.  The way it could be done is to simply mark where the # character occurs, and not go passed that character by simply sticking a null-character in that position.   Even though `strtok` is a horrible function in itself, you don't need all of this code.  The `strtok` function mangles the string anyway, so what difference would it make if you premangled the string by replacing the `#` with a null, and simply call `strtok` as-is?

Comment: I could use a for loop and go through every element in the string or char pointer and set a variable to the placement of '#' in the string like you said. Then perhaps I could run the strtok() function again as many times as the spaces in the trimmed string until it reaches the mark?

Comment: `char *pos = strchr(your_string, '#'); *pos = 0;` -- That is all you really need to do before using `strtok` as-is (no need for special functions to be written).  Is this what you're trying to achieve?  If so, then that entire code you wrote can be thrown away.

Comment: Hmmm now I think I understand. You used strchr() to return a pointer to the first place where '#' occurs then that can be the limit where the strtok() function will tokenize until it reaches that point. Although why did you set ```*pos = 0``` unless that's equivalent to NULL?

Comment: UPDATE:: Using ```mystring.erase(std::find(mystring.begin(), mystring.end(), '#'), mystring.end());``` turned out to work perfectly fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (buf[pos] == '#')
    {
        return token; //return everything before character
        breaker = false; //bool is false so while loop in main will not continue
        break;//break out of the current loop
    }
```

Everything after the return statement is ignored, so you need to arrange it like this:

```
    if (buf[pos] == '#')
    {
        breaker = false; //bool is false so while loop in main will not continue
        return token; //return everything before character
        //break; This line is useless.
    }
```